# Concat values to a nested JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

If I want to concat `name: pancake` to `recipes` I can do this: `initialState.recipes.concat({ name: 'pankake' });`

```
let initialState = {
  recipes: [
    {
      name: 'omelette'
    }
  ]}
```

But If I type `initialState` to the console, it doesn't show me the concat, it only shows me `name: omelette`, why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set `initialState` to the new value, or create a new variable with the new value. `let newState = initialState.recipes.concat({ name: 'pankake' })`

Comment: Or use push: `initialState.recipes.push({ name: 'pankake' })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because concat method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays. You can read it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

you should do:

```
initialState = initialState.recipes.concat({ name: 'pankake' });
```

or

```
initialState.recipes.push({ name: 'pankake' });
```